# Properties of cyclotomic polynomial

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, field-theory, cyclotomic-polynomials

Assume first that $p$ a prime divides $n$. I have to show that $\Phi_{np}(X)=\Phi_n(X^p)$. Here is what I tried:
Suppose $\eta_i$ are roots of $\Phi_{np}(X)$ so $\eta_i=\text{exp}(\frac{2\pi i a_i}{np})$ with $(a_i,np)=1$, but then also $(a_i,n)=1$. Now fill in $\eta_i$ in $\Phi_{n}(X^p)$ and we see $$\Phi_{n}(\eta_i^p)=\Phi_{n}(e^{2\pi i a_i/n})=0$$ because $\eta_i^p$ is a primitive nth-root. We can conclude $\Phi_{np}(X)$ divides $\Phi_{n}(X^p)$.
However, I can not show that they are equal. Because I don't understand how they could be equal. Degree of $\Phi_{np}(X)=\phi(np)<\phi(n)p$ and the degree of $\Phi_n(X^p)=\phi(n)p$, or is this wrong?

Comment: Actually $\phi(np)$ is equal to $\phi(n)p$. You can show this either combinatorially (by exhibiting a map from the elements of $\left\{1,2,...,np\right\}$ coprime to $np$ to the elements of $\left\{1,2,...,n\right\}$ coprime to $n$ and showing that each of the latter elements has precisely $p$ preimages under this map) or algebraically (what formulas do you know for $\phi$ ?). Either way you will have to use $p\mid n$. The primality of $p$ is not needed.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I see, thank you.

Comment: @darij: This is an answer, right?

Comment: Well, up to the fact that it gives no proofs...